# opencv findchessboardcorners assertion failure

Tags: c++, opencv, assert, camera-calibration

I am trying to detect chess board pattern for camera calibration purposes using OpenCV 2.4.2, in Windows 7 + MinGW environment.

I get an assertion failure when calling findChessboard() function. The assertion only happens when the chess board comes in view of the camera.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize, file
>   C:\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 115

I also tried sample\cpp\calibration.exe and get the same result there. Sample source code can be found here:

http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/c5aba337e995eef92704201be2e37773a63b3709/entry/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp

Look at line 468-469:

```
found = findChessboardCorners( view, boardSize, pointbuf,
          CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
```

My own code looks like this:

```
cv::Size patternsize(5, 4), windowSize(11,11), zZone(0,0);
vector<Point2f> corners;

// Find corners
if (findChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, corners,
                          CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH
                          + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
                          + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK)) {

    cout << "pattern detected!";

    cornerSubPix(gray, corners, windowSize, zZone,
      TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));

    // cv::drawChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, Mat(corners), true);
}
```

As mentioned above, control never gets to cout statement. Either findChessboardCorners doesn't find anything (return false) or asserts (when chessboard pattern is detected).

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but to get it out of the way: Is `patternsize` the number of your squares or your inner corners?

Comment: yes, patternSize holds the number of internal corners, for the chessboard, along x and y axes.

Comment: Do you `imshow gray` before calling `findChessboardCorners`? Does it look ok? Could you upload and post a link to one image that fails? Have you tried with different flags in the function?

Comment: Yes, the image looks ok. As I mentioned, 'calibration' sample app in OpenCV works similarly. You can get frames from camera, but as soon as the standard chessboard pattern is brought in front of it, the app crashes, with the same assertion failure.

It is working now with OpenCV 2.3.1. I added Eigen library, which was not being used with my earlier setup.

I'

Comment: It is working now with OpenCV 2.3.1. I added Eigen library, which was not being used with my earlier setup.

I'll try to build OpenCV 2.4.2, with this library and report later today.

Here's the sample image being used: [Chessboard](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_rSc0zPNRAGQ/TCA_XxCI0CI/AAAAAAAAA88/6y3Aq6hPaAI/s1600/chessboard+6x5.jpg)